# Issues rendering pagination with WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having a major issue with trying to render Wordpress pagination. I'm not that good with PHP and I've tried just about every solution I can Google. Some of the queries "work" in that they display a set of page numbers, but they break when I add more variables.

For example, when I told it to display ALL pages, it did just that, but then I couldn't limit it using mid_size or any of that. So it was kind of "display all" (which I don't want), or nothing at all. I'm not sure what's breaking, so any pushes in the right direction would be excellent.

My objective: Create a list of numbered page links that truncate properly so it looks like:

[ 1 2 3 ... 97 98 99 ]

Thanks to anyone who can help me out. I'm running Wordpress 4.9.7.

My code looks like this:

```html
<!-- post loop -->
<div class="auto cell">
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'review', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby'=>'name', 'order'=>'ASC')); ?>
 
<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- start of main news loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
  <div class="cell large-2 small-2">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="thumbnail">
   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
   } else { ?>
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default_thumb.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
   <?php } ?></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell large-10 small-10">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <span class="post-meta"> By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &middot; <?php the_time('F jS, Y, g:i A'); ?> <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit This'), ''); ?></span>
    <ul class="list-meta">
    <li>Developer: <?php echo(types_render_field( 'game-developer' )); ?></li>
    <li>Genre: <?php echo(types_render_field( 'game-genre' )); ?></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="post-categories cell"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>  
 </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- start of pagination -->
  <div class="row">
 <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
          pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
      } ?>
  </div>
    <!-- end of pagination -->
    <!-- end of main news loop -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for my pagination. It gives you a settings screen in the back end where you can set up how it's numbered. Hope it helps!